# why pypy can't load the extension module generated by shedskin

Tags: pypy

I was using PyPy and shedskin. But how can I import module generated by shedskin in pypy? Can anyone give an example to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is just don't. Use pure Python, PyPy's JIT can usually make a lot of sense out of code that shedskin can compile anyway.

The longer answer is that PyPy has a CPython C API compatibility layer (which shedskin uses to create extension modules), but this is what it is - a compatibility layer. It's slow and does not always work. I'm not 100% sure shedskin plays by the rules and always uses the official API instead of poking in internals.

Cheers, fijal